# Windows 8.1 and Debian dualboot EFI problems

Tags: debian, windows, dual-boot, uefi

I am following the instructions described [here](https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLlOd-a2wG0)

My EFI-partition is `/dev/sda2`, but the following command does not work:

```
mount /dev/sda2 /boot/efi
```

It says it cannot find the mount point. I also tried `/mnt/boot/efi` (doesn't work either) and `/mnt/` (works, but grub cannot find the EFI-directory when attempting the steps afterwards).

I skipped the installation of GRUB during the Debian installation because it failed to find my Windows installation and I suspected that it would break the EFI partition if it is not aware of a Windows installation.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: http://superuser.com/a/718188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `/boot` directory does not have an `efi` subdirectory. That's what `mount` was complaining about.

Create it manually:

```
sudo mkdir /boot/efi
```

You will also need a `BIOS Boot Partition` - with `0xEF02` code - to install GRUB on GPT based disk.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have no space between the command **mount** or its arguments.

When you use mount, you are giving it two parameters. 

The first is what you want to mount, the second is where you want to mount it. 
As you have it written, you have one, long, path like that likely doesn't exist. To fix, add the spaces:

```
mount /dev/sda2 /boot/efi
```

If this was somehow just a transposition error, and you actually *did* use spaces, be sure that the directory you are trying to mount to exists.

Comment: I didn't copy-paste the command and I was fully aware that it needed two arguments. It would also probably say something like "Must specify a mount point" if I only passed one argument.

Also the tutorial assumes that it already exists. If Windows can boot and it (GDisk) identifies /dev/sda2 as an EFI partition, then it should also contain /boot/efi or /mnt/boot/efi, but it didn't. Is the tutorial outdated? Is there a difference in these partitions between 8 and 8.1? Note that the command from the Debian tutorial returned "EFI Boot on HDD"

Comment: Let me just make sure I understand where you are at so far... **1.** You installed Windows. **2.** You installed Debian as per your second link. **3.** You ran `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /boot/efi`. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, and during the Debian installation I skipped the installation of Grub because the Debian installer did not detect any OS so I figured it would overwrite the EFI partition.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo mkdir /boot/efi
```

will create the necessary directory.  Perhaps the installer only creates it during the GRUB install, at the point where it decides whether you need the EFI version or not.